# Svelte allowing invalid typescript

Tags: typescript, svelte

I've been using the [template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template) referenced in this [Svelte blog article](https://svelte.dev/blog/svelte-and-typescript) to start learning about Typescript.

The app is building and serving fine. But I have some code like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
    let isDone: boolean = false;
    isDone = 'somestring'
    console.log(isDone)
</script>
```

I'm just starting out in Typescript, but shouldn't this be invalid? I'm not seeing any errors during `npm run build` or `npm run serve`. I don't use VS - is that where you'd expect this to be picked up?

Comment: It looks like the [setup script](https://github.com/sveltejs/template/blob/master/scripts/setupTypeScript.js) adds a `validate` script, have you tried that? It seems like [the rollup plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-typescript) *should* bail out if the type checking fails (which it [certainly does](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAlgzgIgewHYgFwQEYIaAhkiAXggDNdgYQBuAWAChZEUiIByGBAWxBjACcoSAOat6AY2QdQAOmAIhACkbIQASiA)), though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, that script does detect the error. I can integrate that script into my serve and builds myself, but I guess I was expecting that to be already happening here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm run build` executes the build pipeline, which includes preprocessing the TypeScript contents inside Svelte files to JavaScript. This is a transpile-only process, because it happens on a per-file-basis. This means type checking during build would be incomplete/wrong. That's why there's a dedicated package called `svelte-check`, which does the type checking. It's included in the `setupTypeScript.js`-script of the template and can be invoked with `npm run validate`. There's also a watch mode for `svelte-check` if you'd like to run that alongside `npm run dev`. npm Link with a README on all the options: https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-check